# Get content of short-lived file

Tags: windows

I have a tool that generates a set of command-line arguments in a short-lived file (milliseconds or so).  I need the content of the file in order to integrate the tool with other programs.

Is there a way to preserve the content of the file so that I can see what is in it?

Comment: A few reliable if messy approaches... You could use an API hook such as Sysinternals' Process Monitor does to see what data is written to the file.  You could deny the relevant user DELETE permission to the file, so it can be created and then sticks around.  You could rename the tool that reads the file and put your own program in its place that makes a copy of the file contents before invoking the tool that consumes and deletes it.

Comment: If you can open the file quick enough, I think it will stay valid until you're done reading it.

Comment: @Mark: Or you might cause the existing flow to fail entirely, if it tries to open the file for exclusive access (`FILE_SHARE_NONE`).

Comment: An "elegant" but less reliable approach: use a file system watcher (`FindFirstChangeNotification` function) and hope to open and read it before the other program locks or deletes it.  This is going to be very timing sensitive and either you or the existing program that reads the file could fail semi-randomly.

Comment: @BenVoigt For the API hooks, are you talking something like a file system filter drive?

Comment: @Graznarak: Process Monitor may well use a driver for interception of all I/O from all processes, but if you are only interested in one process you can use DLL replacement or Detours.  I mentioned Process Monitor because it isn't very clear from your question whether you know the file has what you need and you need an automated solution for capturing it, or if you still have questions about what data is in the file and would benefit from an existing tool giving you a peek.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know the kind of information that is in the file.  What I need is the details.  I know the file names.